# C - I have a problem with acquiring strings

Tags: c, string, buffer, fgets

I wrote a function that reads and checks strings, but something is wrong, it is as if the stdin buffer is not emptying properly.
I thought so because when I insert the first string in output and press enter, the program simply starts a new line, and I have to reinsert the string and press enter again to make it accepted.

Returns 1 if the string is correct, else 0.

***The function is:***

```
int leggiStringhe(char* stringa, int lunghezza_massima, int lunghezza_minima) {

   unsigned int i = 0;
   unsigned int flag = 0;
   char buffer[MAX_LUNGHEZZA_BUFFER];

   while(getchar() != '\n');

   do {

        fgets(buffer, MAX_LUNGHEZZA_BUFFER, stdin);


        while( buffer[i] != '\n'){
            i++;
        }


        if( i > lunghezza_massima){
            printf("\nHai inserito una stringa troppo lunga, riprova:  ");
        } else if(i < lunghezza_minima) {
            printf("\nHai inserito una stringa troppo corta, riprova:  ");
        }
        else { flag = 1; }

   } while( i > lunghezza_massima || i < lunghezza_minima);

    buffer[i]= '\0';
    strcpy(stringa, buffer);

    return flag;
}
```

P.S: I can't use functions like fflush () or others because I use repl.it.

Comment: You must post this question on - https://italian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English.

Comment: Read a good book such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Be aware that `<stdio.h>` and its `stdin` is often line-buffered. Read about [setvbuf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) and [stdin(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html) and [getchar(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) and don't forget to handle failure cases.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code is not English-friendly

Answer (score 1):

`getchar` reads a character.  `while(getchar() != '\n')     ;`  (extra spaces for emphasis) reads an entire line, one character at a time.  If you are running the program with stdin coming from a tty that is echoing its input, then you are seeing the keys you type (including the final newline) be printed on the screen and consumed (and ignored) by your program.  After the first line is ignored, `fgets` reads the second line.

What are you trying to accomplish with `while(getchar() != '\n');`?